# Reposting quiz questions

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, citing-sources

I found a booklet for bochrim for Bein Hazmanim.

It has lots of fascinating "quiz" questions. No answers provided.

> E.g:
>
> How can women bring Bikurim if it's time bound? Only allowed to bring Bikurim from Shavuot to Chanuka.
>
> Rambam says that Viduy must be done standing, yet he says to do Viduy while putting one's full weight on the Korban during Semicha; so one is not halachicly standing. How can this be the halacha?

I was tempted to post them, one by one.

- Does this go against any forum rules?
- Should I mark them as being "copied"?

  - If yes, in the question or in the body?

Comment: Relevant? http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/139/5323

Comment: Relevant: http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/307

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think there are two aspects to bringing in questions from elsewhere: impact on the source, and impact on the community.

**Impact on the source**

Stack Exchange welcomes questions from anywhere, and in a blog post I can't find now, Jeff Atwood or Joel Spolsky (IIRC) explicitly suggested the following strategy for promoting SE sites: find a question "in the wild", e.g. somebody asking on Twitter, come to SE, ask it, and respond to that person with a link to the answer.  Therefore, from SE's perspective it's completely ok to ask questions that didn't originate with us.

However, both SE and our Jewish values forbid plagiarism.  You should either *ask the question in your own words* or *quote it with attribution*.  The latter should be reserved for questions that are a relatively small part of a larger whole; if a textbook were to present material and end each chapter with a few questions for further thought then I wouldn't see a problem with quoting those questions (with attribution), but if a publication consisted entirely of such questions, I would be hesitant to bring more than a very few of them here in that way.

Re-asking a question in your own words is generally fine.  It's polite to acknowledge the source if the question is particularly insightful or well-sourced -- give credit where it's due -- but if someone at *shul* asked you a run-of-the-mill question and you brought it here, I wouldn't expect you to name the person.  I've described ends of a spectrum and most cases will be in the fuzzy middle ground, so use your best judgement.  For what it's worth, I have re-asked questions from elsewhere to SE and *also* from SE to a blog (where my goal was to post my answers, but I needed questions to hang them on).

**Impact on the community**

We should strive to ask questions that will bring some value to Mi Yodeya.  [Riddles fall below this threshold](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/140/472) (thanks Shokhet for the link), but real questions (that satisfy our scope requirements) are welcome.  Be mindful, however, that there are only so many slots on the front page, which may be the only page many people look at, so try to spread them out.  We want good questions and we also want a good *variety* of good questions.  The front page that naturally evolves contains questions on a variety of subjects, from a variety of people, requiring different levels of expertise to answer.  Please respect that and help keep the site engaging for all.

Comment: So (after reading the above and all the links) it seems that if I (1) make it a quality question with substantial background information and (2) ask them at random intervals and (3) they are useful, as opposed to "trick / riddle" questions and (4) I quote the source if appropriate, then it's within the boundaries of this forum.

Comment: @DannySchoemann, yes, I agree with that.  I look forward to seeing your questions.