# Use the new tag tip feature

Tags: feature-request, tags

We've long had a CYLOR disclaimer in the [halacha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halacha) tag wiki. A few days ago, SE gave [tag specific pop ups](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274634/3187556). Could we enable this here?

What other tags should we have pop-ups for?  What should the pop-ups say?

Please propose messages for other tags as well here. One message + tag per answer, and please make it community wiki so that others can easily work on it.

Comment: related http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/q/1125/759

Comment: Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104821/wanted-a-standard-way-for-a-site-to-have-a-prominent-professional-advice-discla

Comment: I like this idea. There are some other tags that could also use pop-ups - those that name topics that are on our explicit "not automatically on-topic" list, e.g. [tag:history], [tag:hebrew], [tag:yiddish].

Comment: Come up with specific wording and this is do-able.

Comment: One limitation to the usefulness of this is that true newbies are less likely to know to use the [tag:halacha] tag in the first place.

Comment: @IsaacMoses That's what the MSE request you linked above is for, no? (But i just tested, and didn't see it...)

Comment: @Scimonster, the MSE request I linked was not implemented. The newbie sidebar described in Jeff Atwood's answer went away at some point, I guess when we graduated.

Comment: Perhaps in light of the answers, below, the question should be [broadened](http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/2216/edit) to ask what tags and tooltips the community wants and to specify that only one tag and tooltip is sought per answer in order to clarify what votes are for.

Comment: @msh210 How's this?

Comment: @Shog9 What do you think? I think the top few (currently) are good to go.

Comment: @DoubleAA and Shog: But i think it should wait until it's in a non-critical color.

Comment: @Shog9 Update ?

Answer (score 7):

For [halacha](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halacha), how about the existing wording?

> NOTE: Like Wikipedia, this site makes no guarantee of validity, and does not offer professional (particularly rabbinic) advice. Treat information from this site like it came from a crowd of your friends.

Answer (score 7):

[hebrew](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hebrew):

> Questions about the Hebrew language are not on-topic unless they are also related to Judaism.

Based on the close reason.

Comment: I know this is the wording of the FAQ, but can we change it to "Questions about the Hebrew language are not on-topic unless they are also related to Judaism" for this pop-up? (It's a less complex sentence)

Comment: @YEZ It's a CW post, feel free to tweak it...

Comment: Ya, I just wanted some confirmation before unilaterally tweaking a suggestion with upvotes.

Answer (score 6):

[purim-torah-in-jest](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/purim-torah-in-jest):

> This tag should only be used in the few weeks leading up to Purim.  Please read the [info page](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/tags/purim-torah-in-jest/info) for more details. Remember to include the required footer and not to add other tags.

Answer (score 6):

[sexuality](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sexuality):

> Please respect that in the Jewish tradition certain questions, especially certain questions relating to sexuality, are discussed only in private. Such questions will be closed or deleted at the discretion of the moderators or community.  See [here](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/125/4794).

Answer (score 5):

[history](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/history):

> Use this tag for questions about the history of Judaism or about Jewish perspectives on historical event. If this question is about history of Jews or of the State of Israel, consider asking at [history.se](https://history.stackexchange.com).

Comment: I think I'd prefer something akin to http://meta.judaism.stackexchange.com/a/2219, personally. It's shorter and clearer, and doesn't also include the tag wiki (which is arguably unnecessary in the tooltip). So e.g. `Questions about history are not on-topic unless they are also about Judaism.` Perhaps I should post this as another answer here....

Answer (score 5):

[riddle](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/riddle)

> **NOTE:** Riddles are discouraged as questions here. Any riddle questions posted are likely to be closed. See [this link.](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/140)

Answer (score 2):

[health-safety-shmira](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/health-safety-shmira) and [medicine](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/medicine):

> NOTE: For professional medical advice, please contact your physician.

Comment: Do we even need that? We don't claim to be a medical advice site.

Comment: @Scimonster, unfortunately, there are people who think that sources of Halacha advice can also be substitutes for sources of medical advice.

Comment: Perhaps [tag:choleh-sick] should be considered for this tag tip also.

Answer (score 0):

[how-to](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/how-to):

> Use this tag for questions about technique or method -- how to go
>   about doing Judaism related activites.
>
> Questions about halacha should be tagged [halacha]. Questions that ask 
>   for practical halachaic advice are off-topic on Mi Yodeya.

Comment: What danger would this pop-up be averting?

Comment: People thinking that [tag:how-to] allows *psak* questions. I could totally see that happening. (*The rest of it makes it more similar to the [MSO post](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274634) linked to in the question....if you think it's too much you can fix it*)

Comment: But have we ever had a problem like that?

Comment: @Scimonster How long have we had [tag:how-to] for?

Comment: Exactly! I don't think we should add the notice unless we actually have a problem with it.

Comment: @Scimonster Hm.....I'd rather prevent problems than react to them, but I guess we'll let the community vote on the usefulness of the suggestion.

Comment: @Scimonster In any event......do you think it should be shrunk to match the other answers here, or left as is (imitating the MSO post)?

Comment: @IsaacMoses I meant to ask you the above ^^^^^ as well.

Comment: I agree with @Scimonster that measures like this should be reserved for actually-observed problems.

Comment: If we ever use it, probably shrunk, to match our own standard.

Comment: Ok, then. I might shrink it to match anyway. @Scimonster

Comment: @IsaacMoses ^^^^